# Rspec - Formatter 'specdoc' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation'

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm developing a gem. There is a folder titled /spec and it contains 2 files:

```
#spec_helper.rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
require 'my_gem'

#my_gem_spec.rb
describe MyGem do
  it 'should have a version number' do
    MyGem::VERSION.should_not be_nil
  end

  #............
end
```

Then I run it

```
rspec spec
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:491:in `add_formatter': Formatter 'specdoc' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:30:in `block in configure'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:30:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:30:in `configure'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

What does it mean? How to get rid of it?

Here is the bundle's output

```
bundle install
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using my_gem (0.0.1) from source at . 
Using rspec-core (2.12.2) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.12.1) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.12.1) 
Using rspec (2.12.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.4)
```

Comment: If you used gem-this there is an issue [https://github.com/lazyatom/gem-this/pull/6](https://github.com/lazyatom/gem-this/pull/6)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev, look at bundle, there is no gem-this.

Comment: I mentioned this to point that the problem probably in Rakefile...

Comment: I bet this has to do with bundler 1.3.pre, I have the same issue and just upgraded to it. EDIT: Nope, 1.2.3 same deal

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all previous versions of rspec and its dependencies.

```
gem uninstall rspec
gem uninstall rspec-core
gem uninstall rspec-mocks
gem uninstall rspec-expectations
```

Install the correct version of rspec in gem file [install rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
end
```

[see this answer](http://edx-cs169-1x.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/cs-cs169-2x-oracle-of-bacon-homework-autotest-error/2642#2642)